# how can i transfer integer data from page1 to page2?

Tags: java, android

I have two Class page1 and page2. How can i transfer data from page1 to integer in page2 when the button in page1 is clicked

I've tried a couple codes: 
Page1.Class

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = null;
        switch (position) 
        {
        case 0:
            i = new Intent(this, page2.class );
        i.putExtra("Konum", 2);
        break;

        }
        startActivity(i);
```

Page2.Class

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    private Integer konum = intent.getIntExtra("Konum", 0);
```

But doesnt work !
**How can i transfer data from page1 to integer in page2 when the button in page1 is clicked**

EROR :

```
    09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ru.truba.touchgallery/ru.truba.touchgallery.GalleryUrlActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-27 19:50:19.556: E/AndroidRuntime(528):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: "but it doesn't work" what do you mean by that? do you get any error?

Comment: Please add more detail to your question so people can answer it. Is the application crashing? Then post a crash log. Is the value not coming in correctly? Then post what the value you receive in the second intent is. Currently it's very difficult to try to figure out what you're asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android can be helpful

Comment: Thank you justauser it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
  i.putExtra("Value1", 1);
  startActivity(i);
```

and in other activity after oncreate()

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
int value1 = extras.getint("Value1",0);
```

see this detailed tutorial on [Android Intents](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Comment: Why is this substantially different to what the OP is doing and why would it fix the problem?  The code posted looks OK to me but without the logcat or a description of the problem, we can't be sure.  As is often the case, I suspect that the problematic code has not been shown.